# why threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem creates so many event handles?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, windbg

I wrote a program, which calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` every 1 sec. However, it causes big consumption of event handles.

```
class Program
{
    private static Timer _timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(Run, null, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        _timer.Change(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

        Console.ReadLine();
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    static void Run(object state)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((object statex) =>
            {
                int s = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                {
                    int j = i*i;
                    s += j;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            });

        _timer.Change(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }
}
```

By using windbg's `!htrace -diff` command, I found there are really a lot of event handles that are created between two snapshot, and `!htrace -diff` ensures that all of these handles showed are not closed. The handles are like these:

```
Handle = 0x00000000000003d0 - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00000000000046a0, Process ID = 0x0000000000003f50

0x000007fd7932306a: ntdll!ZwCreateEvent+0x000000000000000a
0x000007fd766126cf: KERNELBASE!CreateEventW+0x0000000000000063
0x000007fd6ee0d647: clr!CLREventBase::CreateManualEvent+0x0000000000000028
0x000007fd6ee0e33f: clr!Thread::AllocHandles+0x000000000000005f
0x000007fd6ee0f231: clr!Thread::CreateNewOSThread+0x0000000000000091
0x000007fd6ee0f152: clr!Thread::CreateNewThread+0x00000000000000ae
0x000007fd6ee0f9b1: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateUnimpersonatedThread+0x00000000000000c5
0x000007fd6ee0cccc: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateWorkerThread+0x0000000000000019
0x000007fd6ee0cca5: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::MaybeAddWorkingWorker+0x000000000000011d
0x000007fd6ee0d398: clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x0000000000000024
0x000007fd6ee0d436: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x000000000000002a
0x000007fd6ee0d3d2: clr!ThreadPoolNative::RequestWorkerThread+0x000000000000002f
0x000007fd6dc062ea: mscorlib_ni+0x00000000005662ea
0x000007fd6db3c53e: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000049c53e
……….
Handle = 0x00000000000003cc - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00000000000046a0, Process ID = 0x0000000000003f50

0x000007fd7932306a: ntdll!ZwCreateEvent+0x000000000000000a
0x000007fd766126cf: KERNELBASE!CreateEventW+0x0000000000000063
0x000007fd6ee0d647: clr!CLREventBase::CreateManualEvent+0x0000000000000028
0x000007fd6ee0e331: clr!Thread::AllocHandles+0x0000000000000051
0x000007fd6ee0f231: clr!Thread::CreateNewOSThread+0x0000000000000091
0x000007fd6ee0f152: clr!Thread::CreateNewThread+0x00000000000000ae
0x000007fd6ee0f9b1: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateUnimpersonatedThread+0x00000000000000c5
0x000007fd6ee0cccc: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CreateWorkerThread+0x0000000000000019
0x000007fd6ee0cca5: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::MaybeAddWorkingWorker+0x000000000000011d
0x000007fd6ee0d398: clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x0000000000000024
0x000007fd6ee0d436: clr!ThreadpoolMgr::SetAppDomainRequestsActive+0x000000000000002a
0x000007fd6ee0d3d2: clr!ThreadPoolNative::RequestWorkerThread+0x000000000000002f
0x000007fd6dc062ea: mscorlib_ni+0x00000000005662ea
0x000007fd6db3c53e: mscorlib_ni+0x000000000049c53e
```

And by using `!handle`, I found 124 event handles:

```
187 Handles
Type                 Count
None                 3
Event                124
Section              4
File                 7
Directory            3
Mutant               4
WindowStation        2
Semaphore            2
Key                  10
Thread               21
Desktop              1
IoCompletion         2
Timer                3
TpWorkerFactory      1
```

So, I really wonder why `QueueUserWorkItem` creates so many event handles??? Is this a bug or by design of CLR?
On our production service, since we use `async` operation a lot of, essencially every `async` operation will call CLR’s `QueueUserWorkItem`. I think that is the reason why our service has more than 60000 handles. But, what about if I really want to reduce the number of handles?? So many handles will have a lot of objects in kernel memory, I really want to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: My money's on the Timer, rather than the thread pool, causing the problems.

Comment: IMO, 124 event handles is really NOT a lot for the whole .NET Framework infrastructure. It's too few, actually. Don't do anything, just leave `static void Main() { Console.ReadLine(); }` and see how many you'll get.